# Getting null point exception while posting photo in facebook from my app

Tags: android, facebook

I am getting the following error:

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog.show(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference" while trying to post photo .

this is my code:

```
 Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                                    SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image).build();


                                    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                                    .addPhoto(sharePhoto)
                                    .build();
                                    shareDialog.show(content);
```

Comment: What the message says is that `shareDialog` is null, you need to check this in the earlier code.

Comment: thank you..i am not initialized it before..